# Range Operator for Base62 Encoding

Tags: f#

For base 62 encoding, I need all 62 alphanumeric characters. The F# range operator offers a nice shorthand for this.

```
let alphaNumericCharacters =
    seq {
        yield! [|'a'..'z'|]
        yield! [|'A'..'Z'|]
        yield! [|'0'..'9'|]
    } |> Array.ofSeq
```

This is nice and concise, but I'm greedy. Is there a way of doing this in one line?

Comment: Could you create a github gist with the whole base62 encoding and decoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let alphaNumericCharacters = Array.concat [| [|'0'..'9'|]; [|'A'..'Z'|]; [|'a'..'z'|] |]
```

Answer (score 1):

`let alphaNumericCharacters = ['a'..'z'] @ ['A'..'Z'] @ ['0'..'9'] |> List.toArray`

Answer (score 0):

If your feeling funny:

```
let alphaNumericCharacters = [|Char.MinValue..Char.MaxValue|] |> Array.filter Char.IsLetterOrDigit
```